# How to filter console output in Xcode

Tags: xcode, console, nslog

In my iOS project, I use one 3rd-party library, which is is incredible spamming into the console output. Can I apply any filtering to debug output.

Comment: It may not be a real solution but [MCLog](https://github.com/yuhua-chen/MCLog) is a XCode plugin enabling output filtering.

Comment: @david Thx, I should accept this comment as best answer, because `MCLog` do exactly what I need.

Comment: l've copied my comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Works in Xcode 5.0 through 7.3, [Apple no longer supports Xcode plug-ins as of Xcode 8.0](https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/issues/475).**

[MCLog](https://github.com/yuhua-chen/MCLog) should be what you're looking for.

This is an XCode plugin.

Comment: yeah... not working anymore. github issues state the same and no one seems to care

Answer (score 5):

If the library is using NSLog you can redefine it and discard the log message when it comes from the library. Example code:

```
#define NSLog(args...) [[Logger singleton] debugWithLevel:kDebug line:__LINE__ funcName:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ message:args];

// poor man's nslog
@interface Logger : NSObject

typedef enum {
    kTrace=0, kDebug=1, kInfo=2, kWarn=3, kError=4, KSilent=5
} LoggerLevel;


// ...

@implementation Logger

+(Logger *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Logger *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Logger alloc] init];
        shared.logThreshold = kTrace;
    });
    return shared;
}
-(void) debugWithLevel:(LoggerLevel)level 
                  line:(int)line 
              funcName:(const char *)funcName 
               message:(NSString *)msg, ... {

    va_list ap;         
    va_start (ap, msg); 
    msg = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:msg arguments:ap] autorelease];
    va_end (ap);        

     msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s %50s:%3d - %@", levelName[level], funcName, line, msg];

    // ... filter by class name ...

    fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", [msg UTF8String]);
}
@end
```

Note that `funcName` contains the classname and method sending the message. If the library is a good citizen and has classes that start with a prefix, discard the output if the className starts with that. Otherwise you have to load a list of classes from that library and check them before the fprintf line.

This of course, doesn't duplicate the log to syslogd like NSLog does, but who cares. :P

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you're using directly the 3rd party library source code in your project or a binary library.

If you're using the source code I'd suggest to check what they are using to log the messages. It may have a way to reduce the verbosity. If they are using plain `NSLog` the only option would be to redefine `NSLog` in order to do some filtering, as Jano proposed you.

If they are using low level functions like `printf` and the like, your best option is to replace them with your own custom logging macro, like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_3P
    #define LOG_3P(str) NSLog(@"%s", str)
#else
    #define LOG_3P(str) /* nothing */
#endif
```

Then, replace `printf("a c string message")` with `LOG_3P("a c string message")`. You'll need to customize the solution, adjust macro parameters or even add several macros for your case. And make a few search and replace until it works.

When you want to see the 3rd party library logs, just define `DEBUG_3P` in your build settings as C flags: `-D DEBUG_3P`, otherwise it will be mute.

If you're using a binary library you can just build it with its release configuration, disabling or reducing the logs verbosity to its minimum.

Comment: I use source code library written in C, and it uses printf(), vprintf() and puts() for logging.

Comment: In that case, unless you replace them with your own logging macro, I'm afraid you can't *easily* intercept the output. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift, I wrote a wrapper around print() that does just this. See here: https://github.com/SebastianMecklenburg/TagLog

It works by adding tags to debug messages and then filter the output by those tags. It works all in code and doesn't need an Xcode plugin.

Comment: Will this filter out 3rd party text that's sent to the console via the `print()` command?

Comment: Github link is a 404 now